VueJS changes will not get reflected on webpage even after recompiling
I am running this project in a docker dev container, there are 2 parts to this project's frontend, sist2-admin which works fine and recompiles fine for example when I change the Logo in the navbar and rebuild, the navbar changes on the webpage after a refresh. The second part is the sist2-vue folder, this is where the problem occurs, I try to change basic HTML elements (changing the title) and even after recompiling none of the changes are reflected.
this is my docker-compose.yml file
version: "3"

services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:7.17.9
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - sist2-es-data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    environment:
      - "discovery.type=single-node"
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms2g -Xmx2g"
      - "PUID=1000"
      - "PGID=1000"
    entrypoint: >
      sh -c "chown -R 1000:1000 /usr/share/elasticsearch/data && exec /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh"

  sist2-admin:
    build:
      context: .
    container_name: sist2-admin
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - sist2-admin-data:/sist2-admin/
      - sist2-host:/host
    ports:
      - 4090:4090
      - 8080:8080
    working_dir: /root/sist2-admin/
    entrypoint: python3
    command:
      - /root/sist2-admin/sist2_admin/app.py

volumes:
  sist2-admin-data:
  sist2-es-data:
  sist2-host:


Hi,
i dont see anything in your compose file regarding: sist2-vue. Anyways, its important that each time when the container is started, that the following command is run inside the sist2-vue folder: "npm run build". This applies the changes made in the vuejs (html) and builds them to the build/public directory which is served.
Hope that helps, good luck!
